How to fix Arduino Code connected to LED's?
I have been trying to make an Arduino project about LED's. As you know in Arduino Projects, there are 2 main components, the circuit with the Arduino Board and the physical stuff, and the other one is the Code, which controls it. I think I have a problem with the code, I am 100% sure I have the right circuit, so the code has an error. So my project is this:
Imagine you have 10 LED's next to each other and from left to right they are numbered with the numbers from 0-9 with very small pieces of paper sticked to them. Basically I want to make the number PI light up. I want the LED's to light up correspondingly with the corresponding numbered LED's. So at the first step the LED with the number 3 to light up, then the LED with the number 1 on it to light up and so on. I plan to use PI to about a thousand digits but for now I would use PI=3.141 as you can see in the code below. But when I run the code something very strange happens (I want to point out that it's logical that after the code has ran through the number3, 1, 4, 1, it should get an infinite numbers of 0, because of the way I have defined the computer to read the digits of pi as you can see in the code below). The LED's light up in the following order 3, 4, 7, 6 and then an infinite number of 0's, that's not how it should light. It should light like this: 3, 1, 4, 1 and then an infinite number of 0's. So what's the problem with my code? For context I work on an Arduino UNO and I don't get any red signs for problem in my code. First I define the pins that I will use: from 2-11, then I define the pins as outputs and the in the loop I go through a bit of logic to get the digits of pi and then I make the if else statements to check which of the LED's to light up. I know that my code is probably inefficient, if you have any suggestions please let me know. I am new to coding and I have been inspired by Mark Rober, what an amazing person! This is the code below.
# define led0 2
# define led1 3
# define led2 4
# define led3 5
# define led4 6
# define led5 7
# define led6 8
# define led7 9
# define led8 10
# define led9 11
int change = 1;

void setup() {
pinMode (led0, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led1, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led2, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led3, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led4, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led5, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led6, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led7, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led8, OUTPUT);
pinMode (led9, OUTPUT);

}

void loop(){
  double pi = 0.3141;
  change = change*10;
  int S = change*pi;

  if(S % 10 == 0){
    digitalWrite (led0, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led0, LOW);
  }

  else if(S % 10 == 1){
    digitalWrite (led1, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  }

  else if(S % 10 == 2){
    digitalWrite (led2, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  }

  else if(S % 10 == 3){
    digitalWrite (led3, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  }


else if(S % 10 == 4){
    digitalWrite (led4, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
  }


else if(S % 10 == 5){
    digitalWrite (led5, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
  }

  else if(S % 10 == 6){
    digitalWrite (led6, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led6, LOW);
  }

  else if(S % 10 == 7){
    digitalWrite (led7, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led7, LOW);
  }

  else if(S % 10 == 8){
    digitalWrite (led8, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led8, LOW);
  }

  else if(S % 10 == 9){
    digitalWrite (led9, HIGH);
    delay(200);

    digitalWrite(led9, LOW);
  }

}



Look at the documentation for % in arduino.  https://www.arduino.cc/reference/it/language/structure/arithmetic-operators/modulo/
take particular note of the very last thing at the bottom under Notes and Warnings.

you should use arrays instead of having 9 variables and repeating things 9 times.

The % operator doesn't work with floats.  See the https://www.arduino.cc/reference/it/language/structure/arithmetic-operators/modulo/.
A float would be a poor choice for this anyway as they only have about 6 or 7 digits of precision.  After that they aren't exact.  In order to store 1000 digits you would probably want to use a char array.
